# area and volume in imaginary quaternion coordinates

Tags: geometry

If 4D space is represented by quaternions with real component being time and imaginary components describing 3D space,  will the area in this 3D space be oriented? Will volume be negative? And will this 4D space metric be [+---] ds^2=dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2?

Comment: I think with the area element you are referring to the length element?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Just having quaternions does not imply a unique metric. However, there is a canonical metric given by the norm of the quaternions. Given the quaternion $$q= a + bi + cj + dk$$
its norm is given by
$$|q| = \sqrt{q^* q} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2+ c^2 +d^2}\,.$$
You can see that the norm is that of the Euclidean 4-space. The norm is natural as it has the property
$$ |q_1 q_2| = |q_1| |q_2|$$
where on the left side $q_1 q_2$ refers to the multiplication as quaternions.